# How do I get Bootstrap table of contents to move when scrolled past a certain point?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tableofcontents

I've added the linked Table of Contents to my site, and it's placed about 600px from the top of the web page. Id like for it to stay there until I get to a certain position and then scroll with me.

I have tried changing `data-spy="affix"` to `data-spy="affix-top"` but when it's set as that, once I scroll to where it's at the top of the page it affixes it's self at the bottom of the page and is completely cut off.

http://afeld.github.io/bootstrap-toc/

Essentialy, I would like the same effect as this: 
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_scrollspy_affix2&stacked=h

html

```
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <!-- My CSS file -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"/>
    <!-- Open Sans Google Fonts -->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!-- Makes this page work on phones -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 bg-cover-about">
                <div class="col-lg-12 nav-links-about">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 logo-about">
                            <a href="../beta/index.php">Profile</a>
                          <a href="../beta/work.php">Work</a>
                          <a class="active" href="../beta/contact.php">Contact</a>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 profile-about">
                    <h1>Here's a little bit about me.</h1>
                    <p> I am a designer currently working for the Boston Red Sox. I've had the privilege of working with organizations big to small and have had work featured in Boston Magazine and dailymail.co.uk.<br><br>
          If you’d like to get in touch, feel free to send me a message.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 contact-form">
                <h1>Send me a note.</h1>
                <form name="contactForm" method="post" action="http://formspree.io/email@andrewtimosca.com">
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder='Name'><br>
                    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder='Email'><br>
                    <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder='Subject'><br>
                    <textarea name="message" placeholder='How can I help you?'></textarea><br>
                    <input class="button send" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 bg-footer">
                <div class="col-col-lg-12 col-xs-12 underliner">
                    <a href="../beta/index.php" title="View Profile">Profile</a>
                    <a href="../beta/work.php" title="View Profile">Work</a>
                    <a href="../beta/contact.php" title="View Profile">Contact</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-col-lg-12 col-xs-12 social">
                    <p>You can also find me on <a class="social" href="https://www.behance.net/andrewtimosca" title="Behance"> Behance </a> and <a class="social" href="https://dribbble.com/AndrewTimosca" title="Dribbble">Dribbble</a>.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-col-lg-12 col-xs-12 copyright">
                    <p>Copyright 2016 Andrew Timosca</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <!-- Jquery obove Bootstrap JS file -->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

css

```
 /* CSS */
h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 0 0 15px 0;
    color: #212934;
        padding: 0 10px;
}
p {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}

body {
    height: 100%;
}
.bg-cover{
    background: url(../images/profile.jpg)no-repeat center center;
    height: 660px;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}
.bg-cover-about{
    background: url(../images/headshot.jpg)no-repeat left center;
    height: 450px;
    min-height: 420px;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #bfbfbf;
}
.logo {
    background: url(../images/logo.png)no-repeat left center;
    background-size: 180px 38px;
    padding: 50px 0px 50px 200px;
}

.logo-about {
    background: url(../images/logo_red.png)no-repeat left center;
    background-size: 180px 38px;
    padding: 50px 0px 50px 200px;
}

.nav-links {
    padding-left: 10%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; /* align vertical */
}

.nav-links-about {
    padding-left: 10%;
    margin-bottom: -20px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; /* align vertical */
}

.nav-links a{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 1 px;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);;
    line-height: 34px;
    transition: .2s color linear;
    display: inline-block;
  height: 34px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 0px 7px 0px 7px;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.nav-links-about a{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 1 px;
    color: #8c8c8c;
    line-height: 34px;
    transition: .2s color linear;
    display: inline-block;
  height: 34px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 0px 7px 0px 7px;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.nav-links a:hover {
    color: white;
}

.nav-links-about a:hover {
    color: #262626;
}

.nav-links a.active  {
    color: white;
}

.nav-links-about a.active  {
    color: #262626;
}

.nav-links a.active:Hover  {
    color: white;
}

.nav-links-about a.active:Hover  {
    color: #262626;
}

.profile {
    margin: 70px 0 20px 0px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)
}

.profile h1 {
    font-size: 46px;
    font-weight: 600;
  margin: 0px 0 30px 0px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

.profile p {
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    max-width: 600px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.profile-about {
    margin: 70px 0 20px 0px;
    padding-left: 10%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #262626;
}

.profile-about h1 {
    font-size: 44px;
    font-weight: 600;
  margin: 0 0 10px -3px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: left;
}

.profile-about p {
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    max-width: 600px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #666666;
}

.bg-services {
    min-height: 43vh;
    height:auto;
    height:auto !important;        /* for IE as it does not support min-height */
    height:43vh;
    background-size:cover;
    padding: 30px 0 30px 0;
}

.service {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 190px;
    margin-top: 40px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
}

.service p {
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: rgba(33, 41, 52, .6);
  line-height: 1.6em;
    padding: 0 40px;
    margin: auto;
}

.service.web {
  background-image: url(../images/web-design.png);
}
.service.mobile {
  background-image: url(../images/mobile-design.png);
}
.service.dev {
  background-image: url(../images/development.png);
}

.bg-viewWork{
    height: 15vh;
    background-color:rgba(232, 232, 232, .3);
    background-size:cover;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
  align-items: center;
    justify-content: center
}
.contact-form {
    padding: 0 0 20px 10%;
    min-height: 43vh;
    height:auto;
    height:auto !important;
}
.contact-form h1{
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.bg-footer{
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #262626;
    background-size:cover;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
}

.underliner a{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 13px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1.0);
    line-height: 34px;
    transition: .2s color linear;
    display: inline-block;
  height: 34px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 30px 5px 10px 5px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.underliner a.active,
.underliner a:hover {

}

.social {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
.social p{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: rgba(255,255,255, .4);
  font-weight: 400;
    margin: 0 5% 0 5%;
}

.social a{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    color: rgba(255,255,255, .4);
    transition: .2s color linear;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.social a.active,
.social a:hover {
    color: rgba(255,255,255, .8);
}

.copyright p{
    font-size: 11px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: rgba(255,255,255, .4);
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 75px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.project-type {
    background-color: blue;
    height:auto;
}

#project1,
#project2,
#project3,
#project4,
#project5,
#project6,
#project7,
#project8,
#project9 {
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 90%;
}

nav[data-toggle='toc'] {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

/* Buttons */

.button {
    border-radius: 60px;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 46px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    transition: .2s all linear;
        margin: 0 10px;
}

.button.red {
    border: 2px solid #981b1e;
    color: #981b1e;
        background: rgba(232, 232, 232, .3);
}

.button.red:hover {
    color: #981b1e;
    border-color: #bfbfbf;
}

.button.send {
    border: 2px solid #981b1e;
    color: #981b1e;
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0);
}

.button.send:hover {
    color: #981b1e;
    border-color: #bfbfbf;
}

/* Form */


input {
    width: 50%;
        margin: 20px 0 15px 0;
}

input[type=text] {
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

input[placeholder] {
        font-size: 17px;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        line-height: 1.7em;
        text-align: left;
}

input[type=submit] {
        width:100px;
        margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}

input:focus {
        outline: none;
}

textarea {
    width: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
        border: 0px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    resize: none;
        outline: none;
    resize:none;
    overflow:hidden;
        height: 10em;
        margin: 20px 0 15px 0;
}

textarea[placeholder] {
        font-size: 17px;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        line-height: 1.7em;
        text-align: left;
}
/* Media Queries */

@media only screen and (-moz-min-device-pixel-ratio:1.5), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio:3/2), only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:1.5), only screen and (min-devicepixel-ratio:1.5), only screen and (min-resolution:1.5dppx) {
    .logo {
        background-image: url(../images/logo@2x.png);
    }
    .logo-about {
            background-image: url(../images/logo_red@2x.png);
    }
    .service {
        background-size: 250px 164px;
    }
    .service.web {
        background-image: url(../images/web-design@2x.png);
    }
    .service.mobile {
        background-image: url(../images/mobile-design@2x.png);
    }
    .service.dev {
        background-image: url(../images/development@2x.png);
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:993px) {
    .service {
        float: none;
      margin:0 30px 50px 50px;
      background-position: left center;
        padding: 70px 125px 70px 250px;
      text-align: left;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:750px) {
    .bg-cover {
        height: 540px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, transparent 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 100%), url(../images/profile.jpg)no-repeat center center;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, transparent 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 100%), url(../images/profile.jpg)no-repeat center center;
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, transparent 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 100%), url(../images/profile.jpg)no-repeat center center;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, .45) 100%), url(../images/profile.jpg)no-repeat center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    }

    .bg-cover-about {
        height: 540px;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, transparent 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 100%), url(../images/headshot.jpg)no-repeat left center;
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, transparent 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 100%), url(../images/headshot.jpg)no-repeat left center;
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, transparent 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 100%), url(../images/headshot.jpg)no-repeat left center;
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, .45) 100%), url(../images/headshot.jpg)no-repeat left center;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }

    .service {
    text-align: center;
    background-position: center top;
        float: none;
    margin:0 0px 10px 0px;
        padding: 200px 30px 20px 30px;
    }
    .service p {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    }
    .profile-about {
        padding: 0 0 0 0;
        }
    .profile h1 {
        margin: 0 0% 10px 0%;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .profile-about h1 {
        margin: 0 0% 10px 0%;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .profile p{
        margin: 0 10% 0 10%;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .profile-about p{
        margin: 0 10% 0 10%;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .nav-links {
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
    .nav-links-about {
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 0;
    }
    .contact-form {
        padding: 0 5% 20px 5%;
        text-align: center;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center
    }

    input {
        width: 100%;

    }

    input[type=submit] {
            width:100px;
    }

    textarea {
        width: 100%;
    }


@media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
    .bg-cover {
        height: 325px;
    }
    .bg-cover-about {
        height: 325px;
    }
    .bg-cover-about {
        height: 325px;
    }
    .profile {
        margin: 15px 0 40px 0px;
    }
    .profile-about {
        margin: 15px 0 40px 0px;
    }
    .profile h1 {
        margin: 0 0% 10px 0%;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 22px;
        line-height: 35px;
    }
    .profile-about h1 {
        margin: 0 0% 10px 0%;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 28px;
        line-height: 35px;
    }
    .profile p{
        margin: 0 1% 0px 1%;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 13px;
        line-height: 25px;
    }
    .profile-about p{
        margin: 0 2% 0px 2%;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 13px;
        line-height: 25px;
        padding: ;
    }
    .logo {
        background: url(../images/logo.png)no-repeat top center center;
        background-position: top center;
        background-size: 180px 38px;
        padding: 10px 0 0 0;
        margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    }
    .logo-about {
        background: url(../images/logo-red.png)no-repeat top center center;
        background-position: top center;
        background-size: 180px 38px;
        padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
        margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    }
    .nav-links {
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .nav-links-about {
        margin: 0px 5% 0px 5%;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .nav-links a{
        margin: 40px 3% 0px 3%;
    }
    .nav-links-about a{
        margin: 40px 3% 0px 3%;
    }
    .contact-form h1{
        font-size: 22px;
        font-weight: 600;
    }
    .bg-footer{
        height: 225px;
    }
    .copyright p{
        margin: 50px 0px 0px 0px;
        }
    .button {
        font-size: 1em;
    }
    .button.send{
        font-size: 1.5em;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you are using?

Comment: No not really. I have all the bootstrap files locally. I edited my post with what Id like my menu to look like. The only difference is that the blue area on my size takes up about 70% more of the screen

Comment: Unfortunately, it's hard to diagnose a problem with a framework like bootstrap without seeing the code. Either you're missing some code or, more likely, some code you've added is throwing things off.

Comment: Here hows this? http://andrewtimosca.com/beta/work.htm

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML portion of your code. Outgoing links have no permanence in SO and cannot be used for further reference.